# No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlets, jdbc, mysql-connector

I have a class A which connects to mysql database in my localhost. It works fine in eclipse.
Then I modified the project to call/invoke class A  from a servlet and deployed to tomcat.
I am getting this exception:

```
No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/a
```

and this exception occurs at:

```
DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl, user, password);
```

What is going wrong here? And how can I fix this problem?

Add:
I'm sure the .jar is under WEB-INF/lib, and this is not the problem.
I just figured it out and the problem is that I forgot to add this line:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

Is there anybody knows that why this line is a must in a web application and not in a java project?

Comment: Ensure you have JDBC library for mysql in tomcat-lib folder or WEB-INF/lib folder.

Comment: You haven't needed that Class.forName() call for about eight years. You must be using a very old MySQL connector version.

Answer (score 4):

No suitable driver" usually means that the JDBC URL you've supplied to connect has incorrect syntax or when the driver isn't loaded at all.

When the method getConnection is called, the `DriverManager` will attempt to locate a suitable driver from amongst those loaded at initialization and those loaded explicitly using the same classloader as the current applet or application.(using `Class.forName()`)

Also check that you have `mysql-jdbc.jar` in your classpath. I would suggest to place `.jar` at physical location to `/WEB-INF/lib` directory of your project.Then tomcat will take care for the rest.